# Chromium/Chrome window is black in Ubuntu 16.04/18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, google-chrome, chromium, window

I have installed Chromium and Google Chrome, but the entire Chromium/Chrome window is black in Ubuntu 16.04/18.04. Does somebody know why?

Chromium installed with: `sudo apt install chromium-browser`

Google Chrome installed by downloading from https://www.google.com/chrome/ and double clicking the `.deb` file.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of black Chromium window]

Comment: How did you install them and which version? What model is your graphics adapter? Which graphics driver does it use?

Comment: @kevin-bowen Thanks for approving the edit. The question still shows as "closed". Could you reopen it? Thank you!

Comment: Well, apparently it's not easy to re-open a question. So I'm posting my answer here (and if it ever gets re-opened, I'll submit as a proper answer). You can try running `chromium` or `google-chrome` with this command line option `--disable-gpu` or `--use-gl=angle`. That should allow the window to render properly. Then you can go into the Chromium/Chrome Settings > Advanced, and uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available". Then in the future you won't need the command line options.

Answer (score 4):

Running Chrome with `--use-gl=angle` does the trick for me and I don't have to turn off the 3D acceleration. The command looks like this:

```
google-chrome --use-gl=angle
```

---

However for the normal usage I've modified every `exec` line in `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` and added the mentioned param, so it looks like this (notice there are three occurences of exec):

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --use-gl=angle
```

---

Works in Ubuntu 16.10, VirtualBox 5.1.12

Comment: If this issue is identical to that in another post, please consider flagging this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't solve it by now, the problem is with WebGL2, for more informations, read this:

[Issue 602679](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=602679)

And like is said in the link, the fix for the black screen is running chrome with --use-gl=angle

It worked for me, hope it helps.

Best regards,
Eugen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi, I included the essential part of the answer "the fix for the black screen is running chrome with --use-gl=angle" and I provided the link first because the question was about why is that happening, and I pointed to that issue and then I provided the fix..